# Understanding semantics behind Mockito verify

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito

I have problem understanding the semantics behind the following piece of code.

```
@Test
public void TestAbc() throws AbcException {
    // method to test
    object.handle();

    // assertions
    verify(someThing).someMethod();
    verify(problemObject).problemMethod();
}
```

Where the definition for the handle method is as follows:

```
public void handle() {
    try {
        someThing.someMethod();
        // throws AbcException
        problemObject.problemMethod();
    }
    catch (AbcException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now in my test I am doing `throws AbcException` to keep things syntactically correct but this doesn't really make sense since I am catching the exception within the handle method and is not throwing it further. But the test method translates to "`TestAbc`  throws `AbcException`" which is not really the case. So my problem is why do I need to add `throws AbcException` to my test method even its not thrown? Can someone help me understanding this?

Answer (score 3):

`verify(problemObject)` returns an instance of a Mockito class that is used to specify what you want to verify. In order to allow for the fluent syntax where you can simply call `problemMethod()` on this object, the class implements the interface (or extends the class) that `problemObject` is mocking. Even though `problemMethod()` in this class simply has the effect of checking whether `problemMethod()` was called on the mock, the Java compiler doesn't know this and only sees that you're calling a method whose signature says `throws AbcException`, so you need to handle it.

P.S.: Unless you have other setup code, your mocked `problemMethod` will not actually throw anything - you need to explicitly set the mock up for that:

```
when(problemObject.problemMethod()).thenThrow(new AbcException());
```

Comment: totally makes sense, but the interpretation of my tests is " call handle method and verify that problemMethod is called". I can see that its needed keeping things syntactically correct, but logically it doesnt make much sense as my test method is not (and can not) throw AbcException.

Comment: Well, it's  logical within the logical framework of the programming language's syntax rules. Because of the creative tricks of Mockito, you are in a situation where you have more information than what you can express through the syntax rules ("this method call won't actually throw this exception"), so the syntactic analysis cannot make the correct inference.

Answer (score 3):

`throws` doesn't mean that a method throws an exception. It means that the method **can** throw an exception. Since the `TestAbc()` calls `problemMethod()`, and this method can throw the checked `AbcException`, and you're not catching it in the test method, you must declare it to make the compiler happy.

The exception will, at runtime, never be thrown, because Mockito won't throw that exception. But the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: TestAbc is not calling problemMethod, its just verifying that its called. But from syntax point of view, it totally makes sense.

Comment: It calls it: `verify(problemObject).problemMethod();`.

Comment: isn't it just an assertion? instead of actual call (again semantically)!

Comment: It is an assertion, semantically. But technically, Mockito.verify() takes a ProblemObject as argument, returns a ProblemObject, and you're calling problemMethod() on this returned ProblemObject(). Since this method **can** throw AbcException, the compiler forces you to declare it. The compiler knows nothing about the semantic of the method. All it knows is its signature.

Answer (score 1):

You are forced to add AbcException to the signature of your test because in your assertion you are calling `problemMethod` which has in its signature `throws AbcException`. (I suppose AbcException is a checked exception).

Therefore you must either catch or rethrow this exception. 
`verify` will return an object of type of the one you feed it with, so for java compiler you are just invoking a method which can throw a checked exception and so you are forced to handle it.